# What's the best practice to use tailwind CSS with multiple similar element?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm learning Tailwind CSS. As I understand, if you want to style an element, you add Tailwind utility css class to it. What should I do when I want to style multiple similar elements? For example, I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<table id="t1">
<tr>
<td class="px-2 text-lg"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have three `<td>` elements and I styled the first one. I want them all looking the same. Should I add the same classes to the following two `td` elements? I feel like this approach seems incorrect, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are working with a framework such as `React` or `Vue` etc, You will actually need to do it once if you make a component.
or simply using a `map`.

But if not then you could use `@apply` by making a class containing all the common classes.
this is not a good approach because now you have to name classes by yourself and then remember the name and when you want to change a small detail then you need to go to your CSS file here is how it works for your example:

go to your CSS file where you added directives for `tailwind` layers and add this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
.tdata{
@apply px-2 text-lg;
}
}
```

then in your `html`:

```
<table id="t1">
<tr>
<td class="tdata"></td>
<td class="tdata"></td>
<td class="tdata"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```